# Single Component Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: python, statistics, montecarlo, markov-chains, mcmc

So, let's say I have the following 2-dimensional target distribution that I would like to sample from (a mixture of bivariate normal distributions) -

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def targ_dist(x):

target = (stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x,[0,0],[[1,0],[0,1]])+stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x,[-6,-6],[[1,0.9],[0.9,1]])+stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x,[4,4],[[1,-0.9],[-0.9,1]]))/3
return target
```

and the following proposal distribution (a bivariate random walk) -

```
def T(x,y,sigma):

return stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(y,x,[[sigma**2,0],[0,sigma**2]])
```

The following is the Metropolis Hastings code for updating the "entire" state in every iteration -

```
#Initialising

n_iter = 30000

# tuning parameter i.e. variance of proposal distribution
sigma = 2

# initial state
X = stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-5, scale=10, size=2, random_state=None)

# count number of acceptances
accept = 0

# store the samples
MHsamples = np.zeros((n_iter,2))

# MH sampler
for t in range(n_iter):

    # proposals
    Y = X+stats.norm.rvs(0,sigma,2)

    # accept or reject
    u = stats.uniform.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)

    # acceptance probability
    r = (targ_dist(Y)*T(Y,X,sigma))/(targ_dist(X)*T(X,Y,sigma))
    if u < r:
        X = Y
        accept += 1
    MHsamples[t] = X
```

However, I would like to update "per component" (i.e. component-wise updating) in every iteration. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You first have to compute the marginal PDFs of your target PDF. Then you can sample component-wise `Y[i] = X[i]+stats.norm.rvs(0,sigma,1)` and also accept/reject component-wise (i.e. `r = (marg_targ_dist(Y[i])*T(Y[i],X[i],sigma))/(marg_targ_dist(X[i])*T(X[i],Y[i],sigma))` )

Answer (score 0):

From the tone of your question I assume you are looking performance improvements.
MonteCarlo algorithms are quite compute intensive. You will get better results, if you perform in algorithms on a lower level than in an interpreted language like python, e.g. writing a c-extension.

There are also implementations available for python (PyStan, PyMC3).